# How to detach and attach data cubes on SSAS, Standard SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, bids

I am trying to detach a cube from SSAS, to move onto another disk due to disk space, and attach afterwards. This is fairly easy to do on SQL Server 2008, when you detach/attach an MDF to move from one disk another. Can't this be done also on the Standard Edition MS SQL 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only supported on Enterprise edition, as indicated in the link below http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/c739f324-7fb3-43d2-8838-383e5fbabc72